# Constructing Bayes Factor comparing a single correlation coefficient in the entire sample vs. separate coefficients by group?

Tags: bayesian, partial-correlation

I have a sample consisting of 4 independent groups of participants.  For any two variables within the sample, I would like to quantify the improvement in fit to the data from estimating a separate partial correlation coefficient in each group (H1), vs. having a single coefficient for the entire sample (H0).  The Bayes Factor approach seems ideal because it will enable me to quantify the evidence for H0 (unlike the Chow test).

I see that correlations are often modeled as bivariate normal, and I considered having a single set of parameters mu_x, mu_y, rho, sigma_x, sigma_y under H0 and four separate sets per group under H1, but then the Bayes Factor would be affected by between-group variations in means and standard deviations - not just rho's - and that is not what I want. Also, what would be a good choice of non-informative priors?

Many thanks for considering this question!

Comment: Rather than considering this as a model selection question, I suggest you build a hierarchical model that can encompass both "separate partial correlation coefficient" and "a single coefficient".

Comment: jaradniemi, thanks for the reply but this is outside of my area of expertise.  How would I do this?  How would I determine which of the two is a better fit to the data?